# WSO2 ESB: message processor exponential redelivery

Tags: wso2, exponential, wso2-esb

I use message processors on WSO2 ESB 4.7.0 and I need to deliver a message to endpoint (which can be unavailable).
How would I implement exponential back-off redelivery strategy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This scenario can be covered through a dead letter channel, please refer to the following link on how this can be done.
http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/IntegrationPatterns/Dead+Letter+Channel

Comment: Thanks! Will it make exponential redelivery if I set progressionFactor of the Endpoint, which the message processor uses?

Comment: ESB allows you to define the message retry interval and maximum delivery attempts, if you want to have a progress factor re-delivery then you might have to use a class mediator or a script mediator

Comment: It's possible to write custom mediator (class/script), but I would like to use internal ESB facilities (like [Endpoint-suspendOnFailure-progressionFactor](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB470/Address+Endpoint) ). Will it make redelivery exponential (geometric progression maybe)?

Comment: I dont think this is possible, but writing a custom mediator for this will give you more flexibility to do exactly what you want.